# Dynamically generating checkbox on picturebox in c#

Tags: c#, .net, checkbox, picturebox

I am stuck in creating check boxes in C#. I want to dynamically generate check boxes on my dynamically generated picture boxes on button click. My c# code doesn't work as I expect. Following code generates checkbox on my form but not on picture box.

Please suggest me some idea so that my checkbox gets linked to picturebox

[image: Checkbox on picturebox]

```
private void btndlt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    add_chkbx();   
}

public CheckBox add_chkbx()
{
    CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
    chk.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 190);
    chk.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 30);
    this.Controls.Add(chk);
    return chk;
}
```

Comment: PictureBox can contain child controls. Use `YourPictureBox.Controls.Add(chk);` and align the checkbox according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
public void add_chkbx()
{
    // for each picture box add check box
    foreach (Control cont in this.Controls)
    {
        if (!(cont is PictureBox))
            continue;
        CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
        chk.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 30);
        chk.BackColor = Color.Transparent; // transparent color for checkbox
        cont.Controls.Add(chk);
    }
}

private void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    add_chkbx();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're adding checkbox to your form by:

```
this.Controls.Add(chk);
```

This assigns proper parent to your checkbox. To add any control to any other control that can contain child controls you have to do the same. So for example:

To add checkbox to panel:

```
panel.Controls.Add(chk);
```

To add checkbox to PictureBox:

```
pictureBox.Controls.Add(chk);
```

And so on.

Comment: I tried it.but controls intellisense is not displaying with picturebox.Not able to add control to picturebox.